# If a user select a value from spinner android how to use that to activate an activity

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am new to the `Android` world, I just want to know how the `Spinner` works and how to use the logic in `MVP`.

I am trying to get the `Spinner` value and get that value to select a level in activity.

Comment: We need more explanation, how far are you now on Spinner?

Comment: I created a basic spinner from tutorials provided by android developer site, but i cant understand how to get the value and out of it and depend on the value user select ,i wanna start a new activity if no value is displayed i wanna show toast message no value selected. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner mSpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mSpin);
```

`String result = mSpin.getSelectedItem().toString();`

**And then use result to to whatever you need to do...**

I think it may help you!

Answer (score 0):

you can call Presenter function and pass Spinner is the same as parameter then handling it in Presenter